# Windows are dim but taskbar is bright

Tags: windows-11

This is a very strange behavior where all my windows are quite dim but the icons on taskbar and their pop-ups, and even application menus are bright.

Please see the video at https://imgur.com/a/KQUbSfG. As I select the Chrome window even the full-screen preview is bright but after selecting the windows is dull.

The graphics drivers are not reporting any error.

This will probably go away with a reboot but I thought to check if anyone knows how to fix it if it happens again

Comment: Does it happen after a reboot? If yes, does it happen after a reboot in Safe mode?

Comment: Also update the Video Driver, Monitor Driver if there is one, and give consideration to updating UEFI BIOS with the manufacturer's App.

Comment: Does it dim further if you open the snipping tool (win+shift+S)? It looks more like some software (maybe snagit?) is trying to highlight something or got stuck in that mode

Comment: If this is an HP computer, it could be Focus Mode. [How to enable/disable Focus Mode on HP](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/How-to-enable-disable-Focus-Mode-on-HP-Spectre-14t/td-p/7850309) If it were this, it doesn't not seem to be behaving properly based on your video. The next thing I'd try s booting in Safe Mode like Harry mentioned.